# Is there an Emacs mode for Rscript?

Tags: emacs, r, ess

Is there any usable emacs mode for `Rscript`?

(`Rscript` is the script front-end for the [R](http://www.r-project.org/) language.)

If I type this:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
print(commandArgs(TRUE))
```

and do `indent` in the [ESS](http://ess.r-project.org/) R-mode it indents the first line like crazy, since it sees it as a comment:

```
                          #!/usr/bin/Rscript
print(commandArgs(TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't, but you can force your Rscript into R editing mode by making the second line of the file look like this:

```
# -*- mode: R -*-
```

(More information [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html).)

Comment: Also, if you end them .R (my choice for normal R files) or .r (my choice for littler or Rscript 'scripts') the mode tends get assigned automatically to.

Answer (score 2):

As of version 5.9, ESS will recognize scripts using the Rscript or litter interpreter; see http://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html#New-features.

For reference, to assign a mode to an interpreter, use the interpreter-mode-alist variable. For example,

```
(add-to-list 'interpreter-mode-alist '("Rscript" . r-mode))
```

Any file with a first line like "#!/usr/bin/Rscript" will be recognized as r-mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try [shell-script-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ShMode) - with some [notes on customized indentation](http://keramida.wordpress.com/2008/08/08/tweaking-shell-script-indentation-in-gnu-emacs/)

It indented your code just fine, for me.

Comment: Any reason for the drive-by down-vote? As I said, what I linked to corrected the bad indentation the OP complained about; if this is not helpful, please ignore. If wrong or harmful, downvote -- but do everybody the courtesy of explaining WHY it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to comment out a line, use "##" instead of "#". Double # will put the line at the right position.

Comment: True, and a useful thing to know.  However, in this case, the first line is required to start with `#!` to tell the shell what kind of script it is.